# jQuery Plugin not accessible after loading $.getScript

Tags: jquery, plugins, dynamic, getscript

I am trying to dynamically load a jQuery plugin by calling "getScript" - but it doesn't seem to recognize the initialization function of the plugin.

However, if I simply include the plugin by creating a script tag, the plugin works fine. I cannot use a static script tag because the final product is loaded dynamically via JavaScript that is put on a page that I do not have control of.

I've demonstrated this below with a plugin called jScrollPane:

The first head is the working copy, and the second is the dynamic way. When the dynamic way is run, there is an error that  $('#content').jScrollPane() is not a function!

```
   <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

    </head>



    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/mwheelIntent.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setScroll() {
                $(function () {
                    $('#content').jScrollPane();
                });
            }
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.getScript("http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js", setScroll());
    </script>
</head>
```

The only thing that has changed is that the jquery.jscrollpane.min.js is being loaded by .getScript and then the actually initialization occurs in the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *pass* the `setScroll` function *to* `getScript`, but instead you're actually *calling* it and passing whatever it returns. Lose that final `()`.